# Python, Sqlite - Is there any way to distinguish between an empty result of a query and not been executed in the first place

Tags: python, sqlite

With using only the cursor instance of a sqlite3.connect I want to know if it (cursor instance) has executed a query or not.

```
def f(cur):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    if user decided to:
        cur.execute("select * from aTable Where aCondition")
    return cur
...

if f(cur).fetchone() == None:
   print("No record found")
else:
   ...print records...
```

My problem is that with only using the returning `cur`, I don't know how to distinguish (in the return place) between the situation that user decides **not** to order the **query** and just cancel the search with the situation in which the **result** set is just is **empty**.

In my current code, in both situations the "No record found" message will be display. Is there any trick (for example through sqlite) to specify any query has just been executed regardless of the result?

**Edit:**

Please forgive me for not explaining my situation as it is in the first place (I'm too inexperienced at the field)

The deadened I'm already in is a design as below. I don't wanna use another global variable or changing the childWin class to receive another parameter when instantiating. This way the only channel to interact between two windows seems to be the cur object (which lives up after the cw instance diminished). So what should I do?

```
class mainWin():
    self.cw=childWin()
    self.cur=self.cw.cur
    self.wait_window(self.cw)
    if self.cur==None:
        **whether search has been canceled (by hitting cancel button) or result is empty?**
    else:
        use the returned records

class childWin(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        global con
        self.cur=con.connection.cursor()

    def cancel_button:
        self.destroy()

    def search_button():
        self.cur.execute("select * from aTable Where aCondition")
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: what is `user decided to`? it is not valid object name

Comment: I've added direct answer, but perhaps you can create `self.result = [None]` on `mainWin`, then pass it to `self.cw = childWin(self.result)`, and then append either `None` (empty result) or the result in `search_button()`?  That way the `self.result` list would be `[None]` if the user cancelled, `[None, None]` for an empty result, and `[None, [..records..]]` when there was a result. Definitely hacky, but you seem to be in that territory :-)  (it's a gross simplification of a message queue concept...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're determined to hack your way to the finish, then perhaps the `cur.description` attribute will help you:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x0075B410>
>>> cn = _
>>> c = cn.cursor()
>>> print c.description
None
>>> c.execute('create table foo (n int)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02B6CC60>
>>> print c.description
None
>>> c.execute('select * from foo')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02B6CC60>
>>> print c.description
(('n', None, None, None, None, None, None),)
>>>
```

i.e. `cursor.description` will be a tuple after a select.

I haven't used this myself for this purpose so "buyer be ware", "here lie dragons", etc., etc.

Comment: You re a real pro, it seems like exactly what I need. Tax

Comment: It might be what you want, but I doubt it's what you need ;-)  anyways, good luck with your deadline.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of mismatched abstraction levels.

You're mixing (a) user actions, with (b) fundamental database operations.

User actions should be at a higher level than basic database operations:

```
def user_interaction():
    ...
    if user decided to:
        cur = run_query()
        ...

def run_query():
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from aTable Where aCondition")
    return cur   # open resultset..
```

When writing low level database functions it is usually a good idea to not leave cursors open with pending results since (i) there's a limited number of open cursors that you can have, and (ii) you can block other processes potentially causing a deadlock. Write your database layer so that it returns exactly the data you need, e.g.:

```
def get_foo_record():
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from aTable Where aCondition limit 1")
    return cur.fetchone()

def user_interaction():
    ...
    if user decided to:
        record = get_foo_record()
        if record is None:
            print("No record found")
        else:
            ...do something with record...
```

i.e. you distinguish not-ran vs empty-result by separating user interaction concerns from low-level code and make low-level (database) code as simple and deterministic as you can.

Comment: You must be right that I made a design mistake. But its part of a large gui and I'm racing against the clock. Is there any cure to my problem for time being?

Answer (score 0):

To capture exceptional events (like the user cancels the search) you can use exceptions:

```
def do_search(cur):
    cur=connection.cursor()
    if user cancels:
        raise RuntimeError("canceled")
    cur.execute("select * from aTable Where aCondition")
    return cur

try:
    results = do_search(cur)
except RuntimeError:
    print "User canceled"
else:
    results = list(results)
    if not results:
       print("No record found")
    else:
       ...print records...
```

to your edit: don't mix up GUI and logic. The windows should collect user input, but the search should be done somewhere else. Use additional flag for cancelation:

```
def do_search(condition):
    ... somehow construct select from condition ...
    return records

class mainWin():
    def start_search(self):
        search_window = SearchWindow()
        self.wait_window(search_window)
        if search_window.canceled:
            ... canceled ...
        else:
            records = do_search(search_window.condition)
            ... use the returned records ...

class SearchWindow(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.canceled = True

    def cancel_button(self):
        self.canceled = True
        self.destroy()

    def search_button(self):
        self.canceled = False
        self.condition = "aCondition"
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: I learned a very useful technique, Tnx. Unfortunately it can not to be applied in my case.